# Show div on geolocation

Tags: javascript, css, geolocation, ip-geolocation

are there any scripts available that will show a different div on users location?

What im trying to do is display the correct shipping info dependent on country.

So i have for example 3 divs UK, Europe, USA. UK is set as default the other 2 are hidden. If the script detects the user is from USA it will hide the UK div and show the USA div.

any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, as we all know IP addresses are far from perfect so the best you’re going to get seems to be ~80% accuracy. That said, there are still a lot of great things you can do for those people if you know where they are coming from.

**Here’s all you have to do:** Use the Javascript [given in this page](http://www.adam-mcfarland.net/2009/11/19/simple-ip-geolocation-using-javascript-and-the-google-ajax-search-api/), then on the basis of IP adresses show/hide divisions using javascript.